# How to start dwm in Ubuntu

Tags: window-manager

I'm trying to launch dwm in ubuntu 20.04, so far I haven't been able to do it and I wonder what is the right way to start this window manager. I already clone the repository and compile the file.

This is what I have done so far.

```
$ git clone http://git.suckless.org/dwm
$ cd dwm/
$ make
$ make install clean
```

How can I continue with the start of the dwm window manager? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you have not installed the software with `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install dwm`?  This is in Ubuntu repositories - no need to compile from source.

Comment: @Nmath to have fun with dwm, you need to install it from source. Configuring it means editing the code and recompiling. There are no separate config files. With the binary install, you are fully stuck with how it comes. :-)

Comment: @vanadium that doesn't meet my definition of "fun" ! Do we know if OP wants to get into all of that?  From what you're saying it sounds like a lot more would need to be done before executing `make install` if compiling from source?

Comment: @Nmath I agree, I am not sure. Yet, for compiling, the procedure given can be all that is needed. Who said compiling is difficult ;-) Typically, it is only when the `make` throws errors that compilation can start to become difficult.

Comment: FWIW, "*Because dwm is customized through editing its source code, it's pointless to make binary packages of it. This keeps its userbase small and elitist. No novices asking stupid questions. There are some distributions that provide binary packages though.*" from https://dwm.suckless.org/. OP, did you use `sudo` as appropriate? Also, what did you do to try launching `dwm`? Give details.

Comment: There's [this](https://cannibalcandy.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/installing-and-configuring-dwm-under-ubuntu/) from 2012 but it may provide some pointers.

Comment: I was using startx and x to launch the display manager but it was showing an empty screen, so after looking for a while I found the solution with xdm, a display manager that works really well with dwm.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem I founded following these steps.

1. First I created the files necessary for the display manager to launch dwm.

   ```
   touch $HOME/.xinitrc
   ```
2. Write the command to execute dwm inside the .xinitrc file.

   ```
   echo "exec dwm" >> $HOME/.xinitrc
   ```
3. Installed a different display manager called xdm and then used it as default.

   ```
   sudo apt install xdm
   ```
4. Reboot the PC and dwm was working.